# bypass script for exiftool

Tags: command-line, parameters, conditional-statements

I am trying to pass on parameters to a simple "script" named stamp.sh
Inside it is just one line with the following text:

```
exiftool $1 -alldates .
```

(Sure, the full command will be more complex but for solving THIS problem it is ok).

When I try to run my script I can pass on to it no-space or no-quotes parameters.

eg. when I type

```
./stamp.sh -'if $Model=~/m/i'
```

it works well.
The script will execute:

```
exiftool -'if $Model=~/m/i' -alldates .
```

However when I try

```
./stamp.sh -'if $Model="MI 9"'
```

it creates:

```
Error: File not found - 9"
```

I tried to manipulate with various type of quote ' (single quote) and " (double quote) but it did't help.

I am on Mint Linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried no quotes and escaping the spaces, e.g. `-if\ $Model=~MI\ 9`

Comment: Also, for your last command, I'm assuming you accidentally dropped the tilde and mean `$Model=~"MI 9"`  ?